# NSMutableDictionary is nil

Tags: objective-c, ios6, nsmutabledictionary

So I have created a simple `UITableViewController` that I push onto the `NavigationController`.
I created an `initWithPList` method that reads a `plist` and stores the values into an `NSMutableDictionary` in the `items` `@property` in a `class` called `Settings`.

The `NSMutableDictionary` is populated correctly in the `initWithStyle` method. But in `viewDidLoad`, the `NSMutableDictionary` `items` `@property` of the `Settings` `NSObject` is `nil`.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong any ideas????

Here is some code:

**Showing the** `ViewController`:

```
TestViewController *settingsViewController = [[TestViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped]; 
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:settingsViewController animated:YES]
```

**Initializing the** `TestViewController`:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style{
    
       if (self = [super initWithStyle:style]) {
                
           // Init settings property here
           settings = [[Settings alloc] initWithPList];
           // settings.items has a count of 5 here....which is correct
       }
       return self;
  }
```

`viewDidLoad` **for the** `TestViewController`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
      
      // Check settings object here to see if it still has items

      // settings.items is nil here for somereason??

      NSLog(@"%i", [settings.items count]); // now it's nil here?
    
 }
```

**The** `Settings` `NSObject`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Settings : NSObject {

    NSMutableDictionary *items;
    NSString *path;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *items;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *path;

-(id)initWithPList;

@end
```

**A snippet of the** `@implementation`:

```
@synthesize items;
@synthesize path;

-(id) initWithPList {

    path = [[self documentsDirectory]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Settings.plist"];

    if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:path])
    {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager]copyItemAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Settings" ofType:@"plist"] toPath:path error:nil];
    }

    items = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];   
    return self;  
}
```

Comment: When you say "// Init settings property here", you're technically not.  That `settings` isn't a property reference.  How is it declared?  (Also is this project using ARC?)

Comment: @PhillipMills, I'm guessing by Gabe's use of retain in the property declaration that this project is pre-ARC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@synthesize items;
```

By synthesizing this way, the backing ivar for the property is named `items`. So when you say

```
    items = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

you're assigning directly to the ivar. In pre-ARC manual memory management, any direct manipulation of the ivar has no connection with "retain" property. Retain/release at the ivar level is totally up to you.

Now because you're creating a dictionary by calling `+dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:`, the dictionary is autoreleased. So you've given a persistent variable (the `items` ivar) a transient object. Poof, it's gone!

The solution is to take ownership of the dictionary. Some convenience methods don't have a non-autorelease equivalent, so we'd have to add a `retain` to them. But in this case, there is an equivalent initializer:

```
    items = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

You have ownership. Problem solved. (This also avoids adding anything to the autorelease pool.)

**Extra:**
It's still confusingly dangerous for the ivar have the same name as the property. It's easy to get lulled into thinking that you're getting the attributes of the property whenever you see `items`. First, let's get rid of the explicit declaration of ivars. They're not needed for properties.

```
@interface Settings : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *items;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *path;

- (id)initWithPList;

@end
```

Apple's convention is to prefix ivars with an underscore. If you're using Xcode 4.5, simply omit the `@synthesize` statement entirely. For earlier Xcode, change the synthesize to use a slightly different name for the ivar:

```
@synthesize items = _items;
```

Then `initWithPlist` can say

```
    _items = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

The underscore serves as a reminder: "This is the ivar! Memory management is your problem!" (And so, you dutifully `release` it in the `dealloc` method.)

Comment: So removing the the explicit ivar in the `@interface` I understand but why should I ditch the `@synthesize` statement in XCode 4.5?

Comment: Because doing so is exactly equivalent to the statement `@synthesize items = _items;`

Comment: I didn't realize XCode automatically synthesizes properties in 4.5...Thanks for the information.